# Facing issue in rendering apex:SelectList of salesforce

Tags: rerender, selectlist, immediate

I have a scenario where I'm using the custom dependent picklist and I don't want to bind all data of VF page to the controller so I'm using immediate on action function. My requirement is that I have to reset the field options and selected field every time when the object is changed. So When I select any value in the field and change the object it resets as I want (Like "Website" is selected in field and I change object "Account" to "Contact" it will reset to "--None--") but when there is any value selected which is common ("Name") in both field options it will not change in select-List but the changed value is reflected on VF page ( in selected field). If I remove the immediate it will work fine but with immediate I'm facing this issue. Here is my sample code:
Controller:

```
    public with sharing class PicklistController {
        public List<SelectOption> objects { get; set; }
        public List<SelectOption> fields { get; set; }
        public String selectedObject { get; set; }
        public String selectedField { get; set; }

        public PicklistController() {
            objects = new List<SelectOption>();
            fields = new List<SelectOption>();
            objects.add(new SelectOption('Account', 'Account'));
            objects.add(new SelectOption('Contact', 'Contact'));
            selectedObject = 'Account';
            changeObject();
        }

        public void changeField() {
            system.debug('*****' + selectedField );
        }

        public void changeObject() {
            fields = new List<SelectOption>();
            fields.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
            selectedField = '';

            if (selectedObject == 'Account') {
                fields.add(new SelectOption('Name', 'Name'));
                fields.add(new SelectOption('Website', 'Website'));
                fields.add(new SelectOption('Type', 'Type'));
            } 
            if (selectedObject == 'Contact') {

                fields.add(new SelectOption('Email', 'Email'));
                fields.add(new SelectOption('Name', 'Name'));
                fields.add(new SelectOption('Phone', 'Phone'));
            }
        }
    }
```

VF page:

```
    <apex:page controller="PicklistController" cache="false">
        <apex:pagemessages id="pgmsgId"></apex:pagemessages>
        <apex:form>
            <apex:actionFunction action="{!changeObject}" immediate="true" name="changeObject"  rerender="pbId, pgmsgId">
                <apex:param value="" assignTo="{!selectedObject}" name="prm"/>
            </apex:actionFunction>
            <apex:actionFunction action="{!changeField}" name="changeField" rerender="pbId, pgmsgId"/>
            <apex:pageBlock id="pbId">
                <apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:outputLabel>Object </apex:outputLabel>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1" onchange="changeObject(this.value);return false;">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!objects}"></apex:selectOptions>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

                        <apex:outputLabel>Fields</apex:outputLabel>

                        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedField}" size="1"  onchange="changeField();return false;">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!fields}"></apex:selectOptions>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

                        <apex:outputLabel>Selected Field</apex:outputLabel>
                        <apex:outputText>{!selectedField}</apex:outputText>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Can anyone tell me the reason why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: try binding the <apex:selectList> inside <apex:outputpanel>

Comment: I have tried this also but that's not working too.

Comment: then try <apex:actionregion>. It works for me!

Comment: your saying that if field is already selected , And if try to change the object  in that case : if same name present in selected object then shouldn't be reset  otherwise its should reset ?

Answer (score 0):

If your saying that if the field is already selected , And if try to change the object in that case, if same name present in selected object then field shouldn't be reset otherwise its should reset .

Then just preserve your **selectedField** value in different variable  called **selectedValue** and compare **selectedValue** with your **fields** has same value present. if its has same value then set  **selectedField** with same old value ie.. **selectedValue**. otherwise **selectedField** just make its blank.

> Just replace below function with code .

```
public void changeObject() {
        fields = new List<SelectOption>();
        fields.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));

         system.debug('*****' + selectedField );
        if (selectedObject == 'Account') {
            fields.add(new SelectOption('Name', 'Name'));
            fields.add(new SelectOption('Website', 'Website'));
            fields.add(new SelectOption('Type', 'Type'));
        } 
        if (selectedObject == 'Contact') {

            fields.add(new SelectOption('Email', 'Email'));
            fields.add(new SelectOption('Name', 'Name'));
            fields.add(new SelectOption('Phone', 'Phone'));
        }

        String selectedValue=selectedField;
        selectedField = '';
        for(integer i=0;i<fields.Size();i++)
                   if(fields[i].getValue() == selectedValue) { 
                         selectedField=selectedValue;
                         break;
                   }    
 }
```

Comment: I think you are taking it wrong, I'm not sure. But my case is I want to reset it everytime but when the field value is same in different objects and this same field value is selected and if I change the object that the field will not be changed but it should be changed.

Comment: @RekhaJangir Exactly. I did in above code .